# $\operatorname{Cov}[\vec{X}\cdot({\bf{v}} \operatorname{Cov}[\vec{X},Y]), \vec{X}] = {\bf{v}\bf{v}}^{-1}\operatorname{Cov}[Y, \vec{X}]$?

Tags: statistics

In Shalizi's *Advanced Data Analysis from an Elementary Point of View* p.44, he writes that for a variable $Y$ with a $p$-dimensional vector of predictors $\vec{X}$, and $\bf{v}$ the covariance matrix of $\vec{X}$, that

$$\operatorname{Cov}[\vec{X}\cdot({\bf{v}} \operatorname{Cov}[\vec{X},Y]), \vec{X}] = {\bf{v}\bf{v}}^{-1}\operatorname{Cov}[Y, \vec{X}].$$

I am comfortable manipulating the covariance when it is a functions of one dimensional random variables, but I don't even know where to begin to get the RHS from the LHS. I am especially confused by the meaning of $\vec{X}\cdot({\bf{v}} \operatorname{Cov}[\vec{X},Y])$. If $\vec{X}$ is $p\times 1$ and presumably $({\bf{v}} \operatorname{Cov}[\vec{X},Y])$ is $p\times p$, then the product doesn't make sense to me. Even if this is a typo and it should be written as $\vec{X}^{T}$, I'm not sure I would know what to do.

My only gut instinct is that there is some law of iterated expectations that can be unraveled from the nested covariance in the first argument.

Comment: $\mathbf{v}\text{Cov}(\vec{X}, Y)$ should be $p \times 1$, since $\text{Cov}(\vec{X}, Y)$ is $p \times 1$. But this equality doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a full-matrix notation, note $a \cdot b$ is $a^T b$, or $b^T a$. Also for the ease of typing, let me write your $\mathbf{v}$ in $V$ and suppress the arrow above $\vec{X}$. Moreover, denote $\text{Cov}(X, Y)$ by $a \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}$, hence $\text{Cov}(Y, X) = a^T \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times p}$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X \cdot (Va), X) = \text{Cov}((Va)^TX, X) = (Va)^T\text{Cov}(X, X) = a^TV^TV = \text{Cov}(Y, X)V^TV.
\end{align}

$V^{-1}$ should not be there anyway.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now. I have never seen the notation $a\cdot b$ like this. Upon rereading the original text, I made a typo and the $\textbf{v}$ on the LHS was actually supposed to be $\textbf{v}^{-1}$ but nevertheless, I can follow all the steps.